# Which approach is better and why? Select statements or functions in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Which approach is better and why? Select statements or functions in PL/SQL?

I came across some articles on PL/SQL where it was mentioned that select statements should be replaced by the functions.
Whether this really improves the performance?

Comment: Select statement replaced where exactly? in application code?

Comment: Yes, wherever a select query is being used, call a function instead. This function executes this query and returns the result data. This could be in either a function , procedure or a package.

Comment: Probably because the SQL is stored in the program and its execution plan is computed and cached well in advance ... which may not happen for direct SQL.

Answer (score 0):

When writing PL/SQL, every call to a select statement is a context switch. Context switches are expensive, which is why PL/SQL has the forall statement and other structures that allow you to execute PL/SQL without having to call SQL. Use SQL when you are retrieving data from an object, use PL/SQL when you don't need to fetch from a table.
e.g.
use

```
l_val := trim(l_val);
```

rather than

```
select trim(l_val) into l_val from dual;
```

Both yield the same answer, but the first is much less expensive than the second.

Minimizing context switches will make your code much more efficient:
bad:

```
For eachrec in ( select a, b from table1) loop
   update table2 set c = eachrec.a where d = eachrec.b;
end loop;
```

better:

```
update table2 set c = (select a from table1 where d = b)
    where exists(select null from table1 where d = b);
```

The second method is better because there is only a single context switch, rather than a context switch for each record being updated.

Can someone help me with the update statement? I know there is a way of writing it without doing the "select". Our databases are from vendors who don't believe in primary keys, so I have never got into the habit of using updates on joins.

Comment: Better way here is using MERGE statement. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm

Answer (score 0):

In general, prefer SQL.  SQL can be portable across databases.  Pl/SQL is Oracle only, so it is not portable.  I consider stored procedures to be technical debt for that reason.

Comment: So presumably you regard SQL which uses Oracle specific functions in the same light?

Comment: Yep.  Avoid the Oracle Kool-Aid.

Comment: Hmmm. "Technical debt" is a metaphor, and a glib and somewhat misleading one at that. Whereas paying Oracle's high licence fees and then deliberately choosing to not use the features you bought is demonstrable financial incompetence.